# How to get detail of user by clicking user id using JS Ajax?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

How to get detail of  user by clicking user id? I fetched the data from JSON API.But know i want some more functionality that I make a id as a link   when user click on that link only this id of data will show from JSON API SERVER.I am wondering How this will happen using JS AJAX.Please help.

There is my code.

```
<html>

<body>


      <table class = "src">
         <tr><th>Name</th><th>id</th></tr>
         <tr><td><div id = "Name"></div></td>
         <td><div id = "Id"></div></td></tr>
      </table>



   </body>


<script type="text/javascript">
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

               if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)  {
                  // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
                  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                  // jsonObj variable now contains the data structure and can
                  // be accessed as jsonObj.name and jsonObj.country.
                    var name="";
                    var id="";

                   for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          name += '<a href="">' + jsonObj[i].name + '</a> <br>';
          id+=jsonObj[i].id + '<br>' ;

                  }
        document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = name;
        document.getElementById("Id").innerHTML = id;
               }
               }



             xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to request the data of particular user id again or display the user according to id from already fetched users data?

Comment: Yes I  want to request the data of particular user id again by clicking on id that is displayed.

Comment: why? you already have the data you fetched in the request right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the `id` div and add click listener to them. Inside handler get the id using `e.target.innerText`

```
  document.querySelectorAll("#tab div.userid").forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${ e.target.innerText}`;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                user = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                //handle your user data here      
        })
       xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
       xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Following example finds the users in the array and displays its data.Here no request is made as data is already available in the array.

```js
var users = [];

function getUsers() {
  let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      users = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      let tableString = ` <tr> <th > Name </th> <th > id </th> </tr>`
      users.forEach(obj => {
        tableString += ` <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="name">${obj.name}</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="userid">${obj.id}</div>
      </td>
    </tr>`
      });
      document.getElementById("tab").innerHTML = tableString;
     document.querySelectorAll("#tab div.userid").forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        getDataOfUser(e.target.innerText)
     }))
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function getDataOfUser(id) {
  let user = users.find(useR => useR.id == id);
  document.querySelector(".info-user").innerHTML = `Info of user:
Name:${user.name}<br>
Email:${user.email}<br>
Phone:${user.phone}<br>
Website:${user.website}<br>
`
}
getUsers();
```

```css
#tab td{
   border:1px solid black
   }
.userid{
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
Click on id to get the user data
<table id="tab">
<table>
<div class="info-user">
</div>
```

Comment: I also want to display address,geo and company of user .

Comment: user.address.city , user.company likewise

Comment: Hi bro can you help me getting user info by sending anther http request?